# XSL keeps stipping my Curly Braces for jsRender

Tags: xslt, jsrender, aspdotnetstorefront

I'm using AspDotNetStorefront (this is why I have to use xsl) and my client would like to be able to sort products in a category.  I decided to use tablesorter & use jsrender to render out the template.

I can do everything but create a special link because the xsl is stripping one of my curly braces for the jsrender template.

So I've got an object w/ productImage like /images/blah.jpg  and the following works correctly.

```
<td>{{:productImage}}</td>
```

Great - so I try to put in in a link:

```
<td><a href='{{:productImage}}'>See the image</a></td>
```

And the xsl outputs my template to be:

```
<td><a href='{:productImage}'>See the image</a></td>
```

So it's not being rendered correctly.  I've tried all kinds of ideas over the last couple hours but cannot get this to work correctly.  How do I keep XSL from stipping my curly braces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XSLT sees the [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) in your `{}`. the spec says:

`a double left or right curly brace outside an expression will be replaced by a single curly brace.`

with that said, doubling the amount of curly braces seems to do the trick. The following node put in the XSLT:

```
<something a="{{{{a}}}}"/>
```

produces the following result tree:

```
<something a="{{a}}"/>
```

**UPDATE**: the XSLT 2.0 spec has a little more to say about double `{{` and `}}` in the [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates) section.